# Fallback media image for featured image not working in admin column

Tags: admin, media-library, wp-list-table

I want to display a fallback image if a custom post type does not have a featured image set and displayed in a custom admin table column.
However all that is being output is the image url and not the image from the media library.

I have used `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` to output the image, though I may not be going about it correctly?

```
// fill column header content
function cpt_columns_content($column_id, $post_id) {
    if ($column_id == 'last_modified') {
        echo get_post_field('post_modified', $post_id);
    } else if ('post_thumbs') {
        the_post_thumbnail('xsm_thumbnail');

    // not sure this is the correct way to go?
    } if (!has_post_thumbnail()) {
        // 156 is the specific media image id
        echo wp_get_attachment_image_src(156, 'archive_thumbnail')[0];
    }
}
add_action('manage_professor_posts_custom_column', 'cpt_columns_content', 10, 2);
add_action('manage_campus_posts_custom_column', 'cpt_columns_content', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_get_attachment_image_src(156, 'archive_thumbnail')[0]` will only echo the URL of the image.  You need to add it to html to display the image.  Try this:

```
echo '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_image_src(156, 'archive_thumbnail')[0].'"/>';
```

You could add the width etc as well

```
echo '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_image_src(156, 'archive_thumbnail')[0].'" width=".wp_get_attachment_image_src(156, 'archive_thumbnail')[1]." height=".wp_get_attachment_image_src(156, 'archive_thumbnail')[2]." />';
```

what happens if someone deletes this image though?  Do you have a fallback?

It may be better to add the fallback image to your theme or plugin directory and reference it that way.

*UPDATE*
If you just want to add the image as simply as possible. You could also try this:

```
wp_get_attachment_image( 156, 'archive_thumbnail' );
```

Comment: rudtek, how can I just display the image without using html here?

Comment: rudtek, this is suppose to be the fallback image, if no feature image has been made

Comment: Yep.  Got that.  My question is what if your client deletes this fallback image from the media libarary?  Then what?  That's why I always code mine so they can't.  (ie in the theme or plugin).  I've updated my answer to address your "no html" question as well.

Comment: rudtek, if I was to use an image from my theme image directory as a fallback image, how can I output it without wrapping in html img tags? I have this so far, but its only outputting the url: `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/assets/images/geo.jpg';`

Comment: what do you have against HTML?

Comment: rudtek, I love html :) I prefer to use php when I can.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way without HTML.

Comment: rudtek no problem, thanks for your help